# Aligning two buttons in two columns horizontally Same level

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make this two buttons horizontally into same level **using bootstrap**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col mb-0">
          <h2>h2 text</h2>
          <h4>h4 text</h4>
          <h4>Another h4 text</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <div class="text-center"><button>Button 1</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-0">
          <h2>Right Div</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <button>Button 2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Current the output is something like this.
[image]

But I want to align the two buttons horizontally as below.
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit :  I would prefer a solution without adding any new elements. Using bootstrap only, if possible .Or otherwise using css.

Comment: Couldn't you just put the two buttons in a new row?

Comment: No. I would prefer a solution without adding any new elements. Using bootstrap only if possible .Or otherwise using css.

Comment: @NuwanHarshakumaraPiyarathna I have placed my answer I hope this will fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it using the d-flex class to make the columns flex containers and flex-column class to set their flex-direction to column. Also, added the justify-content-between class to distribute the remaining space between the top and bottom of the column.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col mb-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
      <div>
        <h2>h2 text</h2>
        <h4>h4 text</h4>
        <h4>Another h4 text</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center"><button>Button 1</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col mb-0 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
      <div>
        <h2>Right Div</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="text-left"><button>Button 2</button></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: a solution without adding a new row div (though frankly I think this is a clear, simple solution). You could use absolute positioning. But be careful, in the example below it only works because I know the right column is smaller than the left column. To have it work in all cases requires some fiddling. Honestly I would just go with the row solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col mb-0">
          <h2>h2 text</h2>
          <h4>h4 text</h4>
          <h4>Another h4 text</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <div class="text-center"><button>Button 1</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-0">
          <h2>Right Div</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <button style="position: absolute; bottom: 0">Button 2</button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just put the buttons in a new row, and you're laughing

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col mb-0">
          <h2>h2 text</h2>
          <h4>h4 text</h4>
          <h4>Another h4 text</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-0">
          <h2>Right Div</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col mb-0"><div class="text-center"><button>Button 1</button></div></div>
       <div class="col mb-0"><button>Button 2</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, is there a way to do this without adding new html elements ?

Comment: I've added the beginning of a solution without adding a row, but to make it work always would require some work.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna use pure CSS, then you should add `position: relative` to the parent div of that button element, & apply `position: absolute, bottom: 0`, to that button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <style>
        .btn-at-bottom {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col mb-0">
          <h2>h2 text</h2>
          <h4>h4 text</h4>
          <h4>Another h4 text</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <div class="text-center"><button>Button 1</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col mb-0 position-relative">
          <h2>Right Div</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          <button class="btn-at-bottom">Button 2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```